# Jenkins Job to have both injected Path variable and user's Path

Tags: jenkins, plugins

One of the jobs in Jenkins requires Environment variables to set from an external file(using Env injector plugin). Problem here is I am also adding Path variable in the external file. Because of this, builds are failing as it does not have the system PATH variable. Failing to execute the basic commands like Java, ant, find etc etc. Is there a way to have both PATH variables(injected path and system's path)

Comment: are you using pipeline ?? or a normal build ??

Comment: A normal free style job

Comment: why not just remove the environment variables when you are done with it ...Env injector plugin can be called more than once in different steps

Comment: I am not getting it. I have just 2 steps, one to inject env variables and other is to run a bat script which will use the variables injected in the first step.

Comment: correct so once that is done then revert it back to the original env variables so that the other stuff that you want to do will not cause a conflict

Comment: Ah! I found out the cause. The problem is with the version of the plugin, having the latest version does not support both injected Path and system PATH. I tried downgrading the version and that works.